# Show milliseconds component of DateTime while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, time-format

I am trying to debug something in Visual Studio that requires millisecond precision and it is making it very onerous because the **parameter-less** `ToString()` representation of a `System.DateTime` does not include the milliseconds component.

An example would be when verifying an array of `System.DateTime` is ordered, I want to be able to see the milliseconds component when inspecting from the locals window.

I am **not** asking for assistance with format strings in `DateTime.ToString`

It seems that it inherits from the system globalization settings, which do not allow you to specify a format with milliseconds (for good, obvious reasons):
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: ToString() could receive a format parameter and you can specify milliseconds in the format

Comment: That requires writing code. I'm talking about inspecting the values while debugging.

Comment: You could make a new class that inherits from `DateTime` and override `ToString()` to return the time with the miliseconds. Not the cleanest, but it would get the job done and you could inspect the values in debug.

Comment: What do you mean "that's not appropriate?" This would do it for you:  ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff). What does the dialog you're showing have to do with anything?

Comment: You can use an assembly-level attribute to change how `DateTime`s are formatted in the debugger.  It isn't necessary to create a class.

Comment: Amy is correct, my solution would be overkill. I just thought about it more and you can add a watch in debug that shows the miliseconds property.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc That requires altering the code

Comment: You can change the format in Visual Studio. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp

Comment: So what are you asking?  Your question does not include a question.

Comment: @LewsTherin `DateTime` is a struct and cannot be inherited from.

Comment: @JamesFaix Another good point.  If I wouldn't have read the question so fast, I wouldn't have missed that they wanted to see the millisecond component in debug mode. I only left that comment up for the comment history.

Answer (score 5):

Before I answer, I first want to respond to one of your comments on the question:

> That requires writing code. I'm talking about inspecting the values while debugging.

My answer does involve writing a single line of code; however, it *only* affects the debugger visualizer, and only for *every instance of `DateTime`*, and does not affect the runtime performance of your code.

That said:

You can add an assembly-level attribute [`DebuggerDisplay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) to change how classes are visualized by the debugger.  Here's a basic example from my own code:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("Start={StartDate} | End={EndDate}]", Target = typeof(DateRange))]
```

In the code above, the first argument is a string defining the template you want to see in the debugger.

You can place this in any file, but honestly it belongs in the AssemblyInfo.cs file with the other assembly-level attributes.

Now, I *think* in your case you would want to make the string argument something like this (I haven't tried this):

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString(\"fff\")}", Target = typeof(DateTime))]
```

If that is incorrect, please feel free to let me know and I'll make the necessary corrections.

Comment: That format will work yes. Though I assume OP wants format _including_ milliseconds, not _just_ milliseconds.

Comment: @Evk well, yeah.  the OP did say he's not looking for help with the format string itself, so I think it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding a [watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx#Anchor_2) when in debug. You can watch properties of objects used in your code even if the code itself never accesses those properties. Just watch the `Millisecond` property of your `DateTime` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused what you mean with while debugging.
I assume you're running the application in VisualStudio.

While debugging you will be able to view the Millisecond property with hovering over the property and then click the expand arrow.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.millisecond(v=vs.110).aspx

You could achieve this with VisualStudio and the Add Watch functionality to observe the property or simply use breakpoints.

If breakpoints will make your test result unusable you have to implement a debugging mechanismn which for example writes down the needed infos with Console.WriteLine. Then you can see the results in the Output Window.

Comment: Hovering over the DateTime and expanding its properties, or expanding the properties for dozens of rows in an array is the onerous part ;)